# Google Maps Places API Returning Inconsistent Results (and sorta solution)

Tags: kotlin, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is part question and part solution for anyone who's having a similar issue.

When using the Nearby Search for Google Maps API, increasing the radius search will sometimes not increase the number of results returned, and in some cases reduce them. The query looks like is:

```
val uri = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=${currentLocation.latitude},${currentLocation.longitude}&fields=geometry, name, vicinity, price_level, rating&name=$cuisineType&radius=$distance&rating=$rating&maxprice=$price&key=(my key)"
```

For example, if I search for "Cuban Food" within a 4000 meter radius and get 4 results, increasing to 6000 meters will now only return 3, several at further distances, and fail to return a couple of the previous, smaller radius results.

I solved this by including "rankBy=distance" and removing the radius parameter, and now it seems to return up to 20 results moving outward in distance from the lang/lat coordinates.

The question part is: WHY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Prominence and Distance in Google Maps Nearby Search

> **prominence (default)**. This option sorts results based on their
> importance. Ranking will favor prominent places within the set radius
> over nearby places that match but that are less prominent. Prominence
> can be affected by a place's ranking in Google's index, global
> popularity, and other factors. When prominence is specified, the
> radius parameter is required.

The above statement from the [Nearby Search | Places API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby), mentioned that **prominence** is the default ranking behavior of the Nearby Search. That having said, if you are searching up for places offering Cuban foods, the results being returned are primarily sorted based on how well-known those places are.

This means that expanding the value of `radius` parameter may introduce new, highly prominent results and will potentially displace previously returned results with lower prominence.

Note also that due to factors like distributed and constantly evolving nature of Google Maps, even executing the same Nearby Search query multiple times may return slightly different results. This is an intended behavior as mentioned from the bug raised in Google's Public Issue Tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/119250563

You likely obtained more results when using `rankby=distance` because this option strictly prioritizes sorting based on ascending distance from your specified location, as confirmed in the documentation:

> **distance**. This option biases search results in ascending order by
> their distance from the specified location. When distance is
> specified, one or more of keyword, name, or type is required and
> radius is disallowed.

However, that strict distance-based prioritization means you'll trade highly-rated places that are bit further for seeing results strictly ordered by distance.

Comment: This explains it perfectly, and reminds me to read with more attention to detail. Thank you!